# Обесцвечение картинок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, дизайн

Нужно обесцветить картинку, но не получается..
Пробовала filter: grayscale(100), а результат не такой, как в макете(
Помогите, друзя<3[image: Вот макет, итог которого нужно получить]

[image: Картиночки]

[image: При вводе фильтров получается так]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставляем контраст на минимум - получаем серый цвет, а потом играем с яркостью в дапазоне 0-2, где 0 = черный, а 2 соответственно белый

```
.class {
    filter: contrast(0) brightness(2);
}
```

Пример на цветном логотипе:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 2%;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  filter: contrast(0) brightness(2);
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
  filter: contrast(0) brightness(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmc7.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmc7.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmc7.png">
```